# What is the image:// prefix?

Tags: image, url, uri, protocols, url-scheme

Quote from the Luckysheet [source code](https://github.com/mengshukeji/Luckysheet/blob/f1a92307918a2eeb3992275ca40fe02ef5eefb70/src/controllers/constant.js?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L845):

`image://css/loading.gif`

Is this an image protocol? I've never seen this prefix before, could anyone explain what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's just a prefix used later to differentiate between two types of values:

```js
const luckysheetloadingImage = function (config) {
    if(typeof config.image==="function"){
        return config.image()
    }
    const regE = new RegExp("^(image|path)://");
    const regResult = regE.exec(config.image);
    let imageHtml = '';
    if (regResult !== null) {
        const prefix = regResult[0];
        const type = regResult[1];
        const imageStr = regResult.input.substring(prefix.length);
        switch (type) {
            case "image":
                imageHtml = `<div class="image-type" style="background-image: url(${imageStr});"></div>`;
                break;
```

I would probably have used two different attributes instead of encoding information in the string.

Comment: Thanks, _"two different attributes"_, you mean two separate object properties, like `{ image: '...', path: '...' }`?

Comment: Yes, `type: 'image', path: '...'`